# Button does not work properly

Tags: html, css

1. I'm using button with `position:fixed`. If I hover mouse, it changes as a hand symbol when after scrolled it does not hover.
2. Before scrolling hover works at center of the button not at edges.

   ```
   <form action="response.php">
       <button style=" position:fixed;" >Get Your Result </button>
   </form>
   ```

default position i bring mouse into center of button it works
[image]

same default position hover is not working even mouse cursor on button[image]

finally i scrolled after hover entirely gets disabled

[image]

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/f2rad3cn/.

Comment: use cursor:pointer; in your button style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `z-index` property to your button.
This might be happening because on scroll, your button might be having any other element overlapping it.
FYI: In `z-index`, elements with higher z-index value comes in front.

Comment: Thanks man , it sounds great i added `z-index: 1` in my style it works

Answer (score 1):

I think need to set button type 
Like this

```html
<button type="submit" style=" position:fixed;" >Get Your Result </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here works what you want:

```
<form action="response.php" style="min-height:800px;">
    <button style=" position:fixed; cursor:pointer;" >Get Your Result </button>
</form>
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2rad3cn/)

Comment: the problem is while scrolling new contents come on button so it does not work. but your `cursor:pointer` is correct , Thanks dear

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<form action="response.php">
    <button type="submit" style=" position:fixed;cursor:pointer;" >Get Your Result </button>
</form>
```

Comment: the problem is while scrolling new contents come on button so it does not work. but your `cursor:pointer` is correct , Thanks dear

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this:

```
 <body>
   <form action="response.php">
     <button type="button" style=" position:fixed;" >Get Your Result </button>
   </form>
 </body>
```

styles

```
  button:hover{
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  body{
    height: 2000px;
  }
```

Comment: the problem is while scrolling new contents come on button so it does not work. but your `cursor:pointer` is correct , Thanks dear